# Quick newbie question: where to start creating an HTTP request?

Tags: c#, http

I have a regular C# (console) app,and I want to send a HTTP request to a specified URL and get back a response.  I would have guessed that the object to use would be `HttpRequest`, but I can't find a suitable constructor for that object, and MSDN documentation all assumes you've already got a `HttpContext` from which to get your Request.  In my case I don't - and `HttpContext` also doesn't have a constructor that is intuitively usable - so what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2008/08/29/3544.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you looking for [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)? Note that it's constructor is obsolete:

> Do not use the HttpWebRequest constructor. Use the WebRequest.Create method to initialize new HttpWebRequest objects. If the scheme for the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is http:// or https://, Create returns an HttpWebRequest object.